# Modify WP Query post__in before have_posts()

Tags: wp-query

I have a plugin that is returning post IDs based on `$_GET` data (which searches a secondary DB table). I am attempting to hook into the standard `have_posts()` function called within a taxonomy page to show the results. Since the data is passed in on the actual page, I can't use the normal `pre_get_posts` stand-by, like so:

```
function finder_sort($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_tax(array('location_type')) && isset($_GET['finder_action'])) {
        $query->set('post__in', array(1,2,3,4,5));
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','finder_sort');
```

Because the data returned is not available until after the `$_GET` requests have been read on the page. So - I was wondering if there's anything I can filter in right before the data is output. For example, here is what I have:

```
$locations_found = wp_list_pluck($locations, 'id');
while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    echo '<tr>';
    finder_location_teaser_table();
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

`$locations_found` has a list of IDs - so what I'm looking to do is filter `have_posts` to only include the IDs listed in `$locations_found`.

In addition, I need these posts ordered as they are noted in `post__in`. Since WP 3.5 is going to "fix" this, I've already added in the [Sort Query by Post In](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sort-query-by-post-in/) function fix:

```
if ( version_compare( floatval( get_bloginfo( 'version' ) ), '3.5', '<' ) ) {

    add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'sort_query_by_post_in', 10, 2 );
    function sort_query_by_post_in( $sortby, $thequery ) {
        if ( !empty($thequery->query['post__in']) && isset($thequery->query['orderby']) && $thequery->query['orderby'] == 'post__in' )
            $sortby = "find_in_set(ID, '" . implode( ',', $thequery->query['post__in'] ) . "')";
        return $sortby;
    }
}
```

so - it'd be a mixture of identifying the `post__in` and then specifying the `order_by` param in this magical filter. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## Clarification

The reason I cannot use the meta key (and why I need to return them in the same order they are retrieved by) is because there is a calculation done on each data item that is dependent on another `$_GET` variable (distance based on zip code).

## Addition Info

Added display function that generates query vars

```
function finder_top_filter($term) {

    ob_start(); ?>

    <section id="sort">
        <form name="search" action="" method="get">
            <label for="finder_zipcode"><?php _e('Zip Code', 'finder'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="finder_zipcode" id="finder_zipcode" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['finder_zipcode']) ? $_GET['finder_zipcode'] : ''; ?>" />

            <label for="finder_distance"><?php _e('Radius', 'finder'); ?></label>
            <select name="finder_distance" id="finder_distance">
                <?php
                $finder_dist_options = apply_filters('finder_dist_options', array(
                    '5'   => '5',
                    '10'  => '10',
                    '25'  => '25',
                    '50'  => '50',
                    '100' => '100',
                    '200' => '200'
                ));
                foreach ($finder_dist_options as $key=>$value) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $key . '" ' . (isset($_GET['finder_distance']) ? selected( $_GET['finder_distance'], $key ) : '') . '>' . $value . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
            </select>

            <input type="hidden" name="finder_action" value="search" />
            <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Show/Filter', 'finder'); ?>" />
            <span class="reset"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term); ?>">Reset</a></span>
        </form>
    </section>
    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
}
```

## Update

Based on the recommendation of Stephen Harris, I decided to go the route of a `JOIN` query to alter the data passed to the loop. So, what I've tried is:

```
function finder_join_locations($join) {
    global $wpdb;

    return '';
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'finder_join_locations');

$i = 0;
while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    echo '<tr>';
    finder_location_teaser_table(get_the_ID(), $locations[$i]['distance']);
    echo '</tr>';

    $i++;
}

remove_filter('posts_join', 'finder_join_locations');
```

To see if I can get nothing to show, but that filter is not overriding the `have_posts()` function - any recommendations? What I'd like to do is pass-in via the `post__in` param, so after I get past this initial bump, it's figuring out the correct SQL statement to include my data (as `$locations_found` includes all the post data I need):

```
$locations_found = wp_list_pluck($locations, 'id');
```

Comment: I don't understand why you write "Since the data is passed in on the actual page, I can't use the normal pre_get_posts". You should be able to manipulate the main query from you theme's functions.php file and the $_GET is already available at that stage.

Comment: Hi Zach - so it seems you want to alter the query based on `$locations` - which is only available in the template? How do you set `$locations`? All query manipulation (for the 'main' query) should ideally be done outside the template...

Comment: *"In addition, I need these posts ordered as they are noted in `post__in`"* - this second part is unrelated to the solution to the first part. Please post it as a separate question.

Comment: @StephenHarris To sum up (hopefully), I'm grabbing all of the locations from an external database table - [referencing this article](http://mondaybynoon.com/20100222/store-locator-wordpress-pods/) so this calculation done on the fly, based on the zip code entered - so nothing I can store in postmeta (the distance between), I can only store each individual zip code for the location and then run it through the math to get the returned list

Comment: @Zach sounds like you want do a `JOIN` query to sort by distance on the main query rather than running two separate queries.

Comment: @StephenHarris Updated original question with progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several possibilities for this one.

First, I am not convinced that that you can't use `pre_get_posts` though maybe you'd have to reorganize your code. You don't have to wait for your theme template to use `$_GET`. Try:

```
function tst() {
    // global $_GET; // sometimes necessary
    var_dump($_GET);
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','tst');
```

So I think something like:

```
function finder_sort($query) {
    // I don't know what your complete code for processing $_GET is but
    // that would go here and set $pin
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_tax(array('location_type')) && isset($_GET['finder_action'])) {
        $query->set('post__in', $pin);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','finder_sort');
```

That is one possibility, and from where I sit right now looks like the best one. If for some reason that isn't possible you can always do something like:

```
$locations_found = wp_list_pluck($locations, 'id');
while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    if (in_array($post->ID,$locations)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        finder_location_teaser_table();
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

I am assuming some things about your data. Your question doesn't have all of the necessary information for me to write code with 100% confidence but that is the idea.

Comment: Hey s_ha_dum thanks for the response. Commented on the original question which hopfully gives a little more clarity (includes an article link that explains how the `$locations` are returned as well). Thanks!

Comment: This was more the route I went - was able to hook into the standard `have_posts()` and simply passed along the matched locations to the `post__in` param in `pre_get_posts()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't rely on `$_GET`

I would recommend, instead of relying on `$_GET` data, to add your custom query parameters to the `$query` object, using [**`add_query_arg()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg), and then retrieve that value using [**get_query_var()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).

Say, for example, you've got a query variable `'foo'`, with a value of `'bar'`, such that:

```
`$_GET['foo'] = 'bar'`
```

You could make that key/value pair available to the `$query` object, like so:

```
add_query_arg( 'foo', 'bar' );
```

Do that wherever it is that you're currently appending `&foo=bar` to the URI.

Now, you can retrieve the value of `'foo'` like so:

```
$foo = get_query_var( 'foo' );
```

#### Using `pre_get_posts`

Since you now have a way to retrieve your URI query value independent of `$_GET`, you can use that method inside of a `pre_get_posts` callback:

```
function finder_sort( $query ) {
    if ( $is_main_query() && is_tax( array( 'location_type' ) ) && isset( get_query_var( 'finder_action' ) ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post__in', get_query_var( 'finder_action' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','finder_sort' );
```

Comment: Hey @ChipBennet thanks for the response. Commented on the original question which hopfully gives a little more clarity (includes an article link that explains how the `$locations` are returned as well). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that it matters *how* you get `$locations`. What is important is *how are you adding them to the URL query string*?

Comment: The URL query string looks like this: `?finder_zipcode=19103&finder_distance=10&finder_action=search` So I am then taking `finder_zipcode` and `finder_distance`, plugging them into a function that calculates the valid zip codes/locations and returns the locations (with matching zip codes that match).

Comment: How does `?finder_zipcode=19103&finder_distance=10&finder_action=search` get **appended to the URL string**? Where and how are you doing the append?

Comment: Added display function to original question